Upsert does not work with not null with default
I am upserting the data like this
export const updateChecklistData = async (values: BlueprintChecklistInsert[]) => {
    const { error } = await supabase.getClient().from('blueprint_checklist').upsert(values, { onConflict: 'id' });
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

here if I am doing just insert with data, something like this
{
        "title": "Keyboard",
        "blueprint_id": "f373e251-da55-4d3d-b4f4-69b4c7b26c7a",
        "id": "030d70a9-e681-476d-a9c4-c3a9ef1399ec",
        "order": 1,
        "parent_id": "9a09f8c7-b255-4725-a228-e5b8f79404c1",
        "event_type": "creation",
        "workspace_id": "7db6e71c-a24c-4710-b63a-728c9413a0cf"
    }

this will succeed but if I update/as well as insert, it will throw an error saying

null value in column "created_at" of relation "blueprint_checklist" violates not-null constraint

[
    {
        "id": "b8b1f216-13c9-446c-b2d5-84881ff5cac4",
        "created_at": "2024-07-27T19:10:04.526662+00:00",
        "title": "Laptop",
        "blueprint_id": "f373e251-da55-4d3d-b4f4-69b4c7b26c7a",
        "workspace_id": "7db6e71c-a24c-4710-b63a-728c9413a0cf",
        "event_type": "creation",
        "description": null,
        "order": 0,
        "parent_id": "9a09f8c7-b255-4725-a228-e5b8f79404c1",
        "remind": null,
        "archived": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Keyboard",
        "blueprint_id": "f373e251-da55-4d3d-b4f4-69b4c7b26c7a",
        "id": "030d70a9-e681-476d-a9c4-c3a9ef1399ec",
        "order": 1,
        "parent_id": "9a09f8c7-b255-4725-a228-e5b8f79404c1",
        "event_type": "creation",
        "workspace_id": "7db6e71c-a24c-4710-b63a-728c9413a0cf"
    },
]

in this b8b1f216-13c9-446c-b2d5-84881ff5cac4 record is in DB but this isn't 030d70a9-e681-476d-a9c4-c3a9ef1399ec
My table something like this
create table "public"."blueprint_checklist" (
    "id" uuid not null default gen_random_uuid(),
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone not null default now(),


here created_at have default as now()

"title": "Keyboard" This item in your failure example does not have a created_at field, therefore that field defaults to null.  But you specifically created the table to not allow that field to be null, so you get the error.  Why are you trying to create a record where that field is null?

@JohnGordon, the created_at field has default now() so for the INSERT case that is not an issue.  As to UPDATE the value would already be there, so lack of value would not be an issue.

Define further what the following means?: b8b1f216-13c9-446c-b2d5-84881ff5cac4 record is in DB but this isn't 030d70a9-e681-476d-a9c4-c3a9ef1399ec

@AdrianKlaver If that column had a default value, then I don't see how this error could happen.  So, I'm guessing that column does not actually have a default value, and the create table statement is not genuine.

@JohnGordon, if the column didn't have a default value, then even insert would've failed? I checked and can confirm table does have a default value for created_at.

@AdrianKlaver I meant that b8b1f216-13c9-446c-b2d5-84881ff5cac4 exist in the table so this would be an update operation. where as 030d70a9-e681-476d-a9c4-c3a9ef1399ec does not so it would be an insert operation. Does this answer your question?

I would look at the Postgres log to see what the ORM is actually sending to the database. Make sure you have log_statement set to at least mod. The only thing I can think of is that .upsert is setting missing fields to NULL.

@AdrianKlaver it was supabase issue for me, answered my question. Thanks for trying to help me out.

Per here UPSERT I would set defaultToNull to False.

For supabase, there is a prop but setting defaultToNull to false solved it for me
export const updateChecklistData = async (values: BlueprintChecklistInsert[]) => {
    const { error } = await supabase
        .getClient()
        .from('blueprint_checklist')
        .upsert(values, { onConflict: 'id', defaultToNull: false });
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

